# How to apply iframe video link on website?

Tags: facebook, iframe, live-streaming, facebook-iframe

I’ve been trying to use the iframe code provided by Facebook to Livestream videos on a website at the same time it is streaming on Facebook. Unfortunately, I have not been successful with it. Can someone please clarify what am I missing here? Please see an example of how I’m doing it at the moment.

1. When scheduling a live video and before clicking on the “Schedule Live Video” button, I copy the iframe code available on Facebook. See image below:

[Image 1 iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziE7g.jpg)

2. I usually paste this iframe code on the website but no video is streamed when the Livestream is happening on Facebook. The screen always stays blank. I tested it in JS fiddle as well. For testing purposes, I used the iframe code for the post and the iframe code for the video.

If I use the iframe code for the post, it works fine - the post image display on the screen. See below.

[Image 2 iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJJnu.jpg)

However, if I use the iframe for the video it shows me a blank screen – before and during the Livestream. Image below.

[Image 3 iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBVZ0.jpg)

My question: Is there a way to use the iframe code to Livestream the video on a website at the same time as it is streaming on Facebook? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see in your screenshot that the video is listed as public... it stayed that way, right?  Have you tried a public post from a different page?  Usually stuff like this comes down to permission problems.